# @EnvironmentObject updating property with delay

Tags: swift, swiftui, calendar, swiftui-environment

I am building a calendar-like app that renders calendars month by month. The program contains several calendars (let's say 2 for the purpose of the question, calendar A and B) that store independent data. I have a `@Published` variable `selectedCalendar` defined in an `ObservableObject` class called `EnvironmentClass()` that determines which calendar the various Views should render.

```
class EnvironmentClass: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var calendars: OrderedDictionary<String,CalendarClass> = CalendarClass.sampleData 
    @Published var date = Date() // Today's date
    @Published var selectedCalendar = "A"
}
```

here `date` holds todays date and `calendars` hold data about the calendars.
In the home View there is a menu View from which one can change calendars, called `CalendarsView`. The issue is the following: if I run the app I see a calendar month for which all date cells belong to `"A"` (found with a print statement). When I change calendar to `"B"` from `CalendarsView`, what I see is that only a part of the date cells changes to `"B"`, while some of them remain `"A"`. By debugging with print statement I found out that, after receiving a new information in `env`, the app starts to render the date cells slightly before changing actually calendar in `env.selectedCalendar`.

Few extra info found from debugging:

- The number of cells that remain "A" changes every time I launch the app. Sometimes it's just a couple, other times many.
- The ForEach that renders the date cells (see `calendarGrid` below) when `env.selectedCalendar` changes to `"B"` does it in order but skips some (randomly). Those cells are the ones that will actually change to "B" and are rendered in order right after `env.selectedCalendar` changes.
- If I press a second time the button that changes the View to `"B"`, the month I see is correct in the sense that all the cells belong to `"B"`. At this point, if I press `"A"` the same problem happens (with the same cells).

It looks like the information `env.selectedCalendar = "B"` is injected in `calendarGrid` (see below) with a little bit of delay. Is this the problem? If so, how does one fix it?

I attach the code for `CalendarsView` and `calendarGrid`.

```
import SwiftUI

struct CalendarsView: View {
    
    @EnvironmentObject var env: EnvironmentClass
    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView (.horizontal, showsIndicators: true) {
            HStack (spacing: 30) {
                ForEach(env.calendars.keys, id: \.self) {index in
                    Button(action: {
                        env.selectedCalendar = index
                    }) {
                        Text(index)
                            .font(.headline)
                            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
                    }
                }
            }.padding(.horizontal, 35).padding(.bottom,50)
        }
    }
}
```

(here `env.calendars.keys` contains `"A"` and `"B"`).
The actual calendar View is rendered using a `LazyVGrid`

```
var calendarGrid: some View {
        
        VStack{
            let columnLayout: [GridItem] = Array(repeating: GridItem(), count: 7)
            let firstDayOfMonth = CalendarHelper().firstOfMonth(env.date)
            let startingSpaces =  CalendarHelper().weekDay(CalendarHelper().minusDay(firstDayOfMonth))
            let currentMonth: [Date?] =  Array(repeating: nil, count: startingSpaces) + CalendarHelper().daysInMonthArray(env.date)

// I use currentMonth with few nil values to address the indentation of the weekdays 
// (if the month starts on Friday, I skip startingSpaces=4 date cells).
        
            LazyVGrid(columns: columnLayout) {
                ForEach(currentMonth.indices, id: \.self) { index in
                    if (currentMonth[index] != nil) {
                        DateCell(day: currentMonth[index]!)
                            .environmentObject(env)
                    }
                    else {
                        Text("")
                    }
                }
            }
        }.padding(.horizontal, 25)
    }
```

Any help is very appreciated.

Comment: Looking quickly at your code, the most suspicious part to me is that you're using incides of the `currentMonth` array as IDs for the cells. My first bet would be that when SwiftUI re-renders the view with a new month, it likely preserves some cells using their identity information. If you could provide a sample project with a minimal example, I'd take a deeper look.

Comment: Lazy variables and views are loaded only when needed.

Comment: Instead of creating constants with let , it would be better to have computed var depending built using env (currentMonth). Using let may prevent SwiftUI to know it has to redraw.